# Return value based on condition in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an Entry model in my app and when it's deleted I simply mark is as deleted instead of soft deleting (so original content stays in database). I want to implement a logic in my Serializer class that if an Entry is marked as deleted (boolean field) the field 'content' returns value "deleted" instead of the original content. I have already implemented logic that if it's deleted it cannot be changed.

I've tried using a CharField with source parameter but then it requires to be read-only so that won't work as I still want the content to be write-able.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `data` property?  Fields are normally isolated, they don't see the whole serializer

Comment: @AndrewBacker Where would i override it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SerializerMethodField for this purpose:-

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Entry

    def get_content(self, obj):
        if obj.deleted:
            return "Deleted"
        return obj.content
```

Comment: SerializerMethodFields are read-only. The OP stated that they wanted the content to be write-able.